# No content loads after Facebook iframe

Tags: html, facebook

I have something like this

```
<table>

<cfoutput query="query1">

<tr>
<td>#data#</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=#shorturl#"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none;width:280px; height:25px;" >
<iframe>        
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>#data2#</td>
</tr>

<cfoutput>
</table>
```

I do not know what the problem is, but no other content loads after the iframe tag. #data2# nor any other new row does not load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two opening `<iframe><iframe>` tags instead of an opening and a closing tag: `<iframe></iframe>`. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have not closed your cfoutput or your iframe, the iframe might work but you should be getting a coldfusion error from that code.

Comment: thanks, cfoutput was a typo as I was typing in stack overflow